# Import from ADO.NET Data Services into Excel

Tags: excel, ado.net

I'm playing around with ADO.NET Data Services and would like to import the output from a query into a spreadsheet.  Although Excel 2007 allows me to import the results of a request from the web page, the resulting spreadsheet contains all the XML header info which makes seeing/working with the data impossible for my users.  Can't seem to find a solution.  Any help?  Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Did you go to the Data Tab.
Then **From Other Sources**
and then **XML Data Import**?

Use the URL of the data. I used Jon Udell's Blog feed as a [test](http://blog.jonudell.net/feed/) and it worked.

If I knew of a public ADO.NET Services URL I could test it out.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work properly because feed web services have special xml format which is different from ATOM that is used by ado.net data services.
check out this url for a not very well solution:
http://geeks.netindonesia.net/blogs/andriyadi/archive/2009/07/16/oba-excel-amp-ado-net-data-services.aspx